# (Proof Verification) Analysis I by Tao: Exercise 3.5.10 - Encoding a function as an ordered triple

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I've only completed 2/3 of the problem so far. Can a kind soul please look over my work so far? Don't go easy - if you spot a mistake, please let me know.

Exercise 3.5.10: If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a function, define the graph of $f$, denoted $G(f)$, to be the subset of $X\times Y$ defined by $\{ (x,f(x)) : x\in X \}$

Proposition: Two functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $f': X\rightarrow Y$ are equal if and only if they have the same graph.

Proof (⇒): Assume that $f=f'$, so that $f(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x∈X$. The graph of $f$ is equal to $G(f)=\{(x,f(x)) : x∈X\}$, which can be trivially written as $G(f)=\{(x,f'(x)) : x∈X\}=G(f')$ by substitution.

Proof (⇐): Assume that $f$ and $f'$ have the same domain, codomain, and graphs. By definition, $$G(f)=\{(x,f(x))  : x∈X\}=G(f')=\{(x,f' (x))  : x∈X\}$$

Let $x∈X$ be arbitrary. Let $\gamma = (x,f(x))$ and note that $γ∈G(f)$, so that $γ∈G(f')$ since $G(f)=G(f')$, it follows that $γ=(x_2,f' (x_2 ))$ for some $x_2∈X$ (by the set's construction via the axiom of replacement). Thus $γ=(x,f(x))=(x_2,f' (x_2 ))$, which implies that $x=x_2$  and $f(x)=f' (x_2 )=f' (x)$. Thus $f(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x∈X$, so that the two functions are equal.

Proposition: Let $G⊆X×Y$ be a set with the property that for any $x∈X$, $\{y∈Y : (x,y)∈G\}$ has one (and only one) element. There is a single function $f:X→Y$ whose graph is $G$.

Proof (existence): Define $f:X→Y$ to be
$$f(x)=\text{the object in }\{y∈Y : (x,y)∈G\}$$
$f(x)$ is defined on its entire domain, since $\{y∈Y : (x,y)∈G\}$ is non-empty for any $x∈X$. Additionally, $f(x)∈Y$ for any $x∈X$ by definition, so that the codomain of $f$ is appropriate. Finally, each $x∈X$ gets mapped to a single $f(x)$, since there is only one object in $\{y∈Y : (x,y)∈G\}$ for any $x∈X$. Thus, $f$ is a well-defined function. It remains to show that $G$ is the graph of $f$, i.e.
$$G(f)=\{(x,f(x))  : x∈X\}=G$$

Let $γ∈G⊆X×Y$, so that $γ=(x,y)$ for some $x∈X$ and $y∈Y$. In particular, $y∈\{y'∈Y : (x,y')∈G\}$, so that $y=f(x)$. Thus $γ=(x,f(x))∈G(f)$. Conversely, let $γ∈G(f)$, so that $γ=(x,f(x))$ for some $x∈X$. By definition, $f(x)∈\\{y∈Y : (x,y)∈G\}$, so that $(x,f(x))∈G$ as desired.

Proof (uniqueness): By the first proposition, two functions with equal domain, codomain, and graph are equal. Thus if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $f':X \rightarrow Y$ both have graph $G$, then $f=f'$. Thus $f$ is unique.